# pyspark dataframe to display whole numbers without decimal

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark

In the following code, the data file has all columns as string. One of those columns stores either integers or decimal numbers with a single decimal place (6.1,4.8,3,9.4,6,...etc.). But once the data is loaded into `pyspark dataframe`, it displays integers with single decimal place (for example 3.0) as well.

**Question**: How can we force pyspark to display all integer values without decimals? E.g., 3.0 should display as 3.

```
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df = spark.read.csv(".......dfs.core.windows.net/myDataFile.txt", sep="|", header="true", inferSchema="true")
```

Comment: A column can have only one type, so if it contains only integers except one value that is a floating point number, then the entire column is considered to be floats.

Comment: maybe for your use case you can use `inferSchema="false"` which will make spark load all the column as strings, so that the string `"1"` will be displayed as `1` and not `1.0`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are trying to accomplish exactly - for display purposes, I would generally recommend doing outside of Spark. I generally use Spark primarily for data processing - read the data, perform transformations/calculations, write the data.

Reporting, where display/formatting matters, can be done separately afterwards.

However, if you *must* do your formatting in Spark:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, format_string, lit, when
from pyspark.sql.types import IntegerType

nums = spark.createDataFrame([(6.1,),(4.8,),(3.0,),(9.4,),(6.0,)], "num: float")
nums.select(
    when(
        col("num").cast(IntegerType()) == col("num"),
        format_string("%.0f", col("num"))
    ).otherwise(
        col("num").cast(StringType())
    ).alias("formatted_num")
).show()
```

Which produces:

```
+-------------+
|formatted_num|
+-------------+
|          6.1|
|          4.8|
|            3|
|          9.4|
|            6|
+-------------+
```